# How to mark scenario as failed when the background fails

Tags: jvm, appium, cucumber-jvm

I am using `cucumber` `jvm` with with background before each scenario. When the background fails the test is skipped but in the end is marked as passed (in the `cucumber` report).
How can I mark a scenario as failed once it's background failed?

Answer (score 0):

Technically It is not possible that Scenario pass. For Couple reason,

- Background always run after every scenario.
- Step Definition, You always do assertion to verify background did right job. As you are using Appium, You could verify you are on right page or verify title. It will skipped if you are not using assertion (I believe).
- We used background for Selenium automation and in implementation, We verified Title , page URL and certain elements are there to start test. We use given statement.

  Background:  I login in as system admin

## Scenario: Create customer

Given I am on create customer page (Using Assertion verify How all condition)

When I click "Create Customer"

And Verify Field "Username","Address","Gender" "Cell Number"

And I enter customer detail "BostonStar","Boston Downtown","Female" and "888888"

Then I am able to create customer successfully (Verify message)

## Scenario:Update Customer

Given I am on create customer page (Using Assertion verify How all condition)

When I update created customer "BostonStar" (Verify customer is in list)

And I select customer and click Update "BostonStar"

And I update address from "Boston Downtown" to "Chicago"

Then I am able to update customer successfully

In both scenario Background will do job or not, I will verify in step stage and decide my further step or failed test